# Uploading files to RapidShare using PHP and cURL via their API

Tags: api, file-upload, rapidshare

I'm trying to upload files to RapidShare using their API and PHP with cURL. So far, I've got this code:

```
// Get the RapidShare server to upload to
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=nextuploadserver');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$uploadServer = curl_exec($ch);

// Upload the file to RapidShare
$url = 'http://rs' . $uploadServer . '.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=upload';
$url .= '&login=login';
$url .= '&password=mypass';
$url .= '&filename=' . $filename;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Set post fields
$postFields = array('filecontent' => array('@' . $targetDir . '/' . $id));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);

die($resp);
```

But the only response I get is: `ERROR: Subroutine invalid. (b6ba5d82)`. If I just do this (basically don't send the file with the request):

```
// Upload the file to RapidShare
$url = 'http://rs' . $uploadServer . '.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=upload';
$url .= '&login=login';
$url .= '&password=mypass';
$url .= '&filename=' . $filename;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

I get this response: `ERROR: No files transmitted. (f269d341)`

So I'm guessing there's something wrong with the way I'm sending the file via POST.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add curl parameter

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,(string)filesize($filename));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE,fopen($filename,'r'));
```

and $filename must write full path.
Sorry Im english very little.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, i just hit this problem as well. after trying for an hour or two to find out what's wrong, it turned out to be quite simple and caused by ignoring a single statement in the api document : "GET parameters are ignored if the POST method is used. So if you use the POST method, send **ALL** parameters via POST." for upload to work, sub=upload should also be sent as a POST parameter rather than GET.