# Rapidshare API with PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, rapidshare

```
$FreeUploadServer = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=nextuploadserver"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://rs$FreeUploadServer.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=upload&login=43533592&password=password&filecontent=C:\libs\test.txt"
```

I have no clue why that isnt working, its something to do with the filecontent parameter but i have read the entire documentation about the API and i cant figure it out.

[API Documentation](http://images.rapidshare.com/apidoc.txt)

Comment: In cases like this, I highly recommend the Fiddler web debugging proxy tool.  It can show you what PowerShell is actually sending and what the server's response is.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: ive tried, im going crazy lol. I normally use Charles to debug but i even decided to give fiddler a shot and i cant figure it out.

Comment: What response is the server returning?

Comment: ERROR: No files transmitted. (f269d341) Its a rapid share specific error, while you here i have a question for you, should i be using Invoke-WebRequest instead of Invoke-RestMethod? Whats the difference anyway, you could use ((Invoke-WebRequest "someendpoint").ParsedHTML.Body | ConvertFrom-JSON) to get the same results as Invoke-RestMethod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you use the `-Method Post` parameter/arg combo on the second Invoke-RestMethod call.  Also, take a look at this [SO response to a similar question about using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987651/uploading-files-to-rapidshare-using-php-and-curl-via-their-api).  After looking at the question and answer, it appears that RapidShare requires filling in POST form fields.  In this case you need to specify the `-Body` parameter.  I think you'll use a PowerShell hashtable where each entry corresponds to a form field name/value pair.  Looks like the one field needed is the `filecontent` field. Presumably the value is the file's contents.

Also, when you use POST, you'll have to convert the `GET` query parameters to `POST` form fields e.g.:

```
$url = "http://rs$FreeUploadServer.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi"
$fields = @{sub='upload';login='43533592';password='password';filename='test.txt';
            filecontent=([IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\libs\test.txt'))}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Body $fields -Method Post
```

If `[IO.File]::ReadAlltext()` doesn't cut it perhaps try `[IO.File]::ReadAllBytes()` instead.

Comment: when i do that i get a different error by the way it says: ERROR: Post without content.

Comment: i tried this: Invoke-RestMethod "http://rs$FreeUploadServer.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=upload&login=43533592&password=password&filecontent=C:\libs\test.txt" -Body @{filecontent="C:\libs\test.txt"} -Method Post
 it failed but this time with subroutine failed, would there be a reason to remove filecontent from the URL?

Comment: I think this is close. The kicker is how to actually transmit the content of the file.

Comment: yeah anyway, i shall mark you as the answer cause to tell you the truth i had been playing with -Body, but forgot that in posh you define name/value pairs with a hashtable, im sure ill get it adventually.

Comment: FINALLY. i found it, im going to answer my own question with the solution :D

Comment: @TaylorGibb So how is your solution *any* different than what I posted?  For your function's $File parameter, is that the name of the file or the file's content?  And really, considering I pointed in you in the direction of `-Method Post` and moving the Get query parameters down into the form fields, you down vote my answer.  Seems a bit harsh unless the answer has no redeeming value. :-)

Comment: I never down voted your answer :| in fact i will mark you as correct. I never saw your updated answer until i came to post, but since you method would work as well i guess i can mark you as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a tiny section in the API Documentation that says if you use the POST method all parameters need to be passed in the body. I wrote a function that uploads to RapidShare in PowerShell, i hope this helps people in the future cause this was VERY annoying.

```
function Upload-RapidShare([string]$File,[string]$Name)
{
     $FreeUploadServer = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=nextuploadserver"
     Invoke-RestMethod "http://rs$FreeUploadServer.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi" -Body  "sub=upload&login=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&filename=$Name&filecontent=$File" -Method Post
}
```

Comment: You realize that specifying the body by string like that is exactly equivalent to using a hashtable for the form fields.  If you look in Fiddler when specifying a hashtable for the Body parameter, the HttpRequest's body (as captured by Fiddler) is `filename=test.txt&sub=upload&password=password&login=43533592&filecontent=...`