# Powershell script to Upload log file from local system to http URL

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

How could i upload a log file from my local system to a webpage (http://abc..) using powershell script?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please also provide more detail on what you've tried already.

Comment: You can try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860864/powershell-http-post-file-upload-for-rest-api) too, if file upload is for REST API.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using HTTP, try something like this:

```
    $sourceFilePath = "c:\MyLocalFolder\LocalLogFileName.log"
    $siteAddress = "http://192.168.15.12/DestinationFolder"
    $urlDest = "{0}/{1}" -f ($siteAddress, "DestinationLogFileName.log";
    $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
    $webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyUserName", "MyPassword");
    ("*** Uploading {0} file to {1} ***" -f ($sourceFilePath, $siteAddress) ) | write-host -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Yellow
    $webClient.UploadFile($urlDest, "PUT", $sourceFilePath);
```

Comment: Care to elaborate for HTTPS?

Comment: Is it the same for HTTPS?

Comment: I run this script and I got this error Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "The remote server 
   returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."At 
   C:\ABCDEF-documents\upload-file.ps1:36 char:13
   +             $webClient.UploadFile($urlDest, "PUT", $sourceFilePath); any clue how to solve it