# Upload file via http using powershell

Tags: php, powershell, http, upload

I want to upload to my host via PowerShell.

But this is not possible for me and I face various obstacles.
I came across the internet to find the answer

```
$uri = "http://myurl.com/uploader.php"
$txtpath="C:\Users\masod\Desktop\tt.txt"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method  post  -InFile $txtpath
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$file_name = $_FILES['UploadedFile']['name'];
$target_path = "uploads/".$file_name;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "ok";}
else {
echo "no ok";}
?>
```

Comment: this is my php code
<?php
$file_name = $_FILES['UploadedFile']['name'];
$target_path = "uploads/".$file_name;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "ok";}
else {
echo "no ok";}
?>

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164723/uploading-file-to-http-via-powershell and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672760/powershells-invoke-restmethod-equivalent-of-curl-u-basic-authentication ?

Comment: excuse me
It did not help me. Could my code be damned?

Comment: It could be, however, I am not experienced in using powershell for uploading files. So I might be wrong.

Comment: It is ridiculous
There is no one to answer my question

Comment: Would be great if you further elaborated on the obstacles you mention. Please provide them. Especially if you get an exception. This would make it easier to supply an answer.

Comment: It's too banal
Just look at the my code. You will understand the routine.
I want to upload a file from my system to the host using a http.
PowerShell will simplify my work. Actually, everything is true and not encountered error, but the upload does not happen