# Invoke-WebRequest error: no parameter like "-form"

Tags: powershell, httprequest

for some reason I got stuck with an simple `Invoke-WebRequest`. I need to send an XML-File to a website by Method "POST" and enc-Type "multipart/form-data". My code:

```
$SupraliftXML="C:\supralift.xml"
$Uri = 'https://www.supralift.com/servlet/EcutServlet?handler=BulkloadHandler&jfaction=0'
$Form = @{
    muddledPassword  = 'mypassword'
    userID   = 'myuserID'
    XMLfile  = Get-Item -Path $SupraliftXML
}
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form
```

I got an error that there is no parameter like "-form"

> $Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The `-Form` Parameter was introduced in PS 6.1.0 . Make sure what Version you are using with `$host.Version`. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6  -  "This feature was added in PowerShell 6.1.0."

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164723/uploading-file-to-http-via-powershell , this basically solves your problem.