# PowerShell 7 - Invoke-WebRequest - use form parameter to send byte array as file

Tags: forms, powershell, invoke-webrequest, system.array

My Powershell 7 script reads JPG files from a content service.

```
$fetch = @{
   Uri = 'https://content.site/media?id=82348'
   Method = GET
}
$fetchResponse = Invoke-WebRequest @fetch
```

Image data loads into `$fetchResponse.content` as a byte array.  Now I must send to a local web server.

```
$ingest = @{
   Uri = 'https:\\internal.site\ingest'
   Method = POST
   Form = @{
      file = $fetchResponse.content
      id = '82348'
   }
}
$ingestResponse = Invoke-WebRequest @ingest
```

Sending the byte array directly as above does not work.  Image data is not detected in the received form.

If I first save the image locally and then use Get-Item to point to the file, it is successful.  I do not want to save the images locally if avoidable.

Does the byte array need to be converted to another format to use the form parameter in Invoke-WebRequest?

Edit: after a bit of circular questioning and answering in the comments, maybe the question is better asked as, "How do I convert a variable's byte array to System.IO.FileInfo without having to write a file to disk?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading file to HTTP via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164723/uploading-file-to-http-via-powershell)

Comment: You need to take the body of the $fetchResponse and put into the body of the $ingest.  Your POST is referencing a filename for the image instead of the body.  When you send the POST you also must include the HTTP Header Content-Type and indicate the data in binary data. See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-content-type/?force_isolation=true

Comment: @shahkalpesh No, the first answer uses -Infile, which is a local file reference.  I already have the image data in my response variable, so I don't want to have to write the file locally first.  Plus, that answer doesn't allow the other form fields to be sent.  The second answer has the same limitations, a locally saved file and no way to include the other form fields.

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand.  The file is one field of many in the form.  If I send as the entire body, how are other form fields included?  The Form parameter looks like it should work, but in ["Example 4: Simplified Multipart/Form-Data Submission"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission) on Microsoft's Invoke-RestMethod page, it's sending info of a local file as System.IO.FileInfo.  I want to reference the byte array already retrieved, not a local resource.

Comment: Multi-part is MIME where each attachment starts on a new line with two dashes.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng I understand the MIME format, but Invoke-RestMethod's -Form parameter should simplify all this, I thought.  Are you saying I can't use -Form?

Comment: Read definition of form.  Form expects a Dictionary input.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng I _am_ formatting as dictionary input.  In my example, I define `file` and `id` as keys.

Comment: You asked the question : "Does the byte array need to be converted to another format to use the form parameter in Invoke-WebRequest?"  The answer is Yes.  It need to be a dictionary.

Comment: Shouldn't the byte array go into the `-Body` of your web request?

Comment: Hi @Santigo Squarzon, I'm trying to get this working with the `-Form` parameter because there are multiple form fields.  Microsoft's [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3#-form) says `-Form` and `-Body` are mutually exclusive.