# How to send multipart/form-data with PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm trying to send a file via Invoke-RestMethod in a similar context as curl with the -F switch.

Curl Example

```
curl -F FileName=@"/path-to-file.name" "https://uri-to-post"
```

In powershell, I've tried something like this:

```
$uri = "https://uri-to-post"
$contentType = "multipart/form-data"
$body = @{
    "FileName" = Get-Content($filePath) -Raw
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType $contentType -Body $body
}
```

If I check fiddler I see that the body contains the raw binary data, but I get a 200 response back showing no payload has been sent.

I've also tried to use the -InFile parameter with no luck.

I've seen a number of examples using a .net class, but was trying to keep this simple with the newer Powershell 3 commands.

Does anyone have any guidance or experience making this work?

Comment: Did u tried this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251965/rapidshare-api-with-powershell

Comment: Multipart messages are not supported.  You can set the content type to be anything, but setting it to `multipart/form-data` does not cause the message to be formatted as [multipart](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html).

Comment: Multipart/form-data does work when adding as content type.  The problem I had here is the API needed some parameters to accept raw content, then I was able to use -InFile \path\to\file and upload using Invoke-RestMethod

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here was what the API required some additional parameters.  Initial request required some parameters to accept raw content and specify filename/size.  After setting that and getting back proper link to submit, I was able to use:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: What were the additional parameters you had to add?  I'm having the exact same problem using the ShareFile api...

Comment: Really depends, did you read http://api.sharefile.com/rest/docs/resource.aspx?name=Items

You can try something like this:

sf/v3/Items($parentFolderId)/Upload?method=standard&raw=true&fileName=$fileName&fileSize=$fileSize

Obviously replacing those variables with your data

Comment: The question I have is was this specific to the API you were trying to use or would this be a general requirement for file uploads using multipart posts? JIRA's [API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5037) only lists an example with curl (and mentions some header requirements), with no other post parameters.

Comment: This doesn't create the multipart body format required, the body will not have the `boundary=------------------------abcdefg1234` parts separating the content. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25075010/516748

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer won't do a `multipart/form-data` request, but rather a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request forcing the `Content-Type` header to a value that the body does not contain.

One way to send a `multipart/form-data` formatted request with PowerShell is:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$fieldName = 'file'
$filePath = 'C:\Temp\test.pdf'
$url = 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php'

Try {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Net.Http'

    $client = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient
    $content = New-Object System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent
    $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($filePath)
    $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($filePath)
    $fileContent = New-Object System.Net.Http.StreamContent($fileStream)
    $content.Add($fileContent, $fieldName, $fileName)

    $result = $client.PostAsync($url, $content).Result
    $result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
}
Catch {
    Write-Error $_
    exit 1
}
Finally {
    if ($client -ne $null) { $client.Dispose() }
    if ($content -ne $null) { $content.Dispose() }
    if ($fileStream -ne $null) { $fileStream.Dispose() }
    if ($fileContent -ne $null) { $fileContent.Dispose() }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to supply cookies or credentials with this method?

Comment: If you are going to make multiple HTTP multiple times (i.e. run this in a loop), you shouldn't dispose the `HttpClient ` instance: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 7):

I found this [post](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/396726/PowerShell-V3-Multipart-formdata-example) and changed it a bit

```
$fileName = "..."
$uri = "..."

$currentPath = Convert-Path .
$filePath="$currentPath\$fileName"

$fileBin = [System.IO.File]::ReadAlltext($filePath)
$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$LF = "`r`n"
$bodyLines = (
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"$fileName`"",
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$LF",
    $fileBin,
    "--$boundary--$LF"
) -join $LF

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $bodyLines
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering (like Jelphy) whether David's answer can be used with cookies/credentials, the answer is yes.

First set the session with Invoke-WebRequest:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$LoginUri" -Method Get -SessionVariable 'Session'
```

Then POST to the Login URL, which stores the authentication cookie in `$Session`:

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$Uri" -Method Post -Body $Body -WebSession $Session
```

[The steps above are the standard way to deal with session in Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--use-a-stateful-web-service). But here is the important part. Before creating the HttpClient, create an HttpClientHandler and set it's CookieContainer property with the cookies from the session:

```
$ClientMessageHandler = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
$ClientMessageHandler.CookieContainer = $Session.Cookies
```

Then pass this object to the HttpClient constructor

```
$Client = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new($ClientMessageHandler)
```

Voila, you now have an HttpClient with session cookies set automatically via Invoke-WebRequest. The rest of David's example should work (copied here for completeness):

```
$MultipartFormData = New-Object System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent
$FileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($FilePath)
$FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FilePath)
$FileContent = New-Object System.Net.Http.StreamContent($FileStream)
$MultipartFormData.Add($FileContent, $FieldName, $FileName)

$Result = $Client.PostAsync($url, $content).Result
$Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

I had many files to upload with each request, so I factored out this last bit into a lambda function:

```
function Add-FormFile {
    param ([string]$Path, [string]$Name)

    if ($Path -ne "")
    {    
        $FileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($Path)
        $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($Path)
        $FileContent = [System.Net.Http.StreamContent]::new($FileStream)
        $MultipartFormData.Add($FileContent, $Name, $FileName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update Powershell 7+

[**`Invoke-RestMethod`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4#example-4-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission) and [**`Invoke-WebRequest`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4#example-6-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission) now both accept a **`-Form`** parameter that takes a hashtable like this:

```
$Uri = 'https://api.contoso.com/v2/profile'
$Form = @{
    firstName  = 'John'
    lastName   = 'Doe'
    email      = 'john.doe@contoso.com'
    avatar     = Get-Item -Path 'c:\Pictures\jdoe.png'
    birthday   = '1980-10-15'
    hobbies    = 'Hiking','Fishing','Jogging'
}
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form
```

You can check your current version with `$PSVersionTable`

### See Also

- [powershell invoke-restmethod multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36268925/1366033)
- [multipart/form-data file upload with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68677742/1366033)