# Upload a file to Box.com using Powershell

Tags: rest, powershell, box-api

I am working on a series of Powershell scripts for my company to use to transfer data to and from Box.com. The one thing I just can't figure out is uploading files. The Box API requires a multipart POST operation for uploads, and I've seen a few answers here on SO indicating that I should be able to do that in Powershell (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491129/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-powershell-invoke-restmethod)). But I can't seem to get it working.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
Function Post-File {
    Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
            [string]$SourcePath,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]            
            [string]$FolderId = ############
    )

    #Variables for building URIs
    $baseUrl = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content"

    #Set Authorization for API requests
    $headers = @{}
    $AccessToken = Refresh-Tokens #A reference to another function that definitely works
    $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $AccessToken")

    #Set POST content
    $body = @{}
    $body.Add("filename",  [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourcePath))
    $body.Add("parent_id", $FolderId)

    #Upload the file
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -Body $body
}
```

Here's the response I get back:

```
{
 "type":"error",
 "status":400,
 "code":"invalid_request_parameters",
 "help_url":"http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors",
 "message":"Invalid input parameters in request",
 "request_id":"1764475572534bcddfe04b7"
}
```

I've also tried a couple of other permutations that aren't working. I've tried using the `-InFile` switch in `Invoke-RestMethod` instead of `-Body`. I've also tried using `Get-Content -Raw` in place of `[IO.File]::ReadAllBytes`. Both of those return a more generic error: `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`.

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with my `filename` parameter not being correct, but I'm not sure how to fix it. According to the [Box API](https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file), here's what it should look like in curl. Can someone help me properly translate this for Powershell?

```
https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F filename=@FILE_NAME \
-F parent_id=PARENT_FOLDER_ID
```

Comment: From Spray 1.1.1 server, gives the error: "Content-Type with a multipart media type must have a non-empty 'boundary' parameter"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple things that make this a little tricky in PowerShell:

1. The `filename` parameter specifies the name of the file, not the contents.
2. A request body is required in order to specify the file name and destination.
3. PowerShell treats `-InFile` and `-Body` arguments as mutually exclusive.
4. PowerShell does not appear to natively support `multipart/form-data` POSTs, per the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491129/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-powershell-invoke-restmethod) that you referenced.

Since the request body is required (1,2) -- and thus `-InFile` can't be used (3) -- I think you might need to roll your own `multipart/form-data` body (4) that contains the necessary metadata and file content. [This blog post](http://joe-pruitt.ulitzer.com/node/1006737/mobile) describes a method for doing so. The content there is a short string (a tweet) but the principle is the same.

Below is a Fiddler trace of an upload I just performed using the Box Windows SDK. This shows how the request should look as it goes across the wire. The `$BOUNDARY` is an arbitrary, unique string -- a GUID works great.

```
POST https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="$BOUNDARY"
Host: upload.box.com
Content-Length: 2118
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

--$BOUNDARY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="$FILENAME"

<THE CONTENT OF $FILENAME>    

--$BOUNDARY

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

{"parent":{"id":"$PARENT_FOLDER_ID"},"name":"$FILENAME"}

--$BOUNDARY--
```

Here is the response I received:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 12:52:33 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Length: 364
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

{"total_count":1,"entries":[{"type":"file","id":"$ID","name":"$FILENAME", ... }]}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I have a feeling it may take me a while to implement this, but I'll definitely start working on it and accept this answer if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hot dog! Glad that helped.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg Would you consider posting back how you rolled your own?  There are many SO questions where people are struggling with this.

Comment: Ditto @JeffRosenberg 's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I may sound dumb, but what happens when you do this?

```
$body.Add("filename",  $([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourcePath)))
```

Comment: Same response, I'm afraid. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment to the original and this one is pretty old, but here is how I 'rolled my own' multipart/form-data:

```
    $boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()

    # Read file into memory
    # encoding required to prevent corruption of file on upload
    $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")  
    $fileContent = $enc.GetString([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName))

    # the body syntax, including line breaks, is very specific
    $body = "--$boundary"
    $body += "`r`n" + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' + $($file.Name) + """"
    $body += "`r`n" + 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
    $body += "`r`n"
    $body += "`r`n"
    $body += $fileContent
    $body += "`r`n" + "--$($boundary)--"

    # header will contain the application access token
    $headers = @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken"
        'Content-Type'   = "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"
    }

    $uploadEndpoint = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content?filename=$($file.Name)&parent_id=$folderId"

    $fileUploadResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadEndpoint -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
```