# Powershell: Uploading file to Docparser API using Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: rest, powershell, curl, file-upload

```
$header = @{'Authorization'='Basic <auth code value>'}
$ping = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.docparser.com/v1/ping" -Headers $header
```

ping works fine...returns "pong". I then make a request for the Parser ID which is needed for uploading documents. I am able to retrieve this value successfully.

```
$parser = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.docparser.com/v1/parsers" -Headers $header
$parserID = $parser.id
```

Now here is where I try to upload a pdf, which fails.

```
$fileToParse = "C:\test.pdf"
$body = @{'file'=$fileToParse}
$uploadDoc = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.docparser.com/v1/document/upload/$parserID" -Method Post -Headers $header -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' -Body $body
```

API response keeps saying "Error: input empty"

This is the documentation from Docparser on how to upload pdfs:
[image]

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your body currently just contains the path to your local file. [Docparser](https://docparser.com) expects however the content of the file as multipart/form-data.

I never worked with PowerShell, but I think something like this should work for you:

```
$body = @{
    "file" = Get-Content($fileToParse) -Raw
}
```

I got the code from this answer: [How to send multipart/form-data with PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491129/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-powershell-invoke-restmethod)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw that post as well but was not able to get it to work with that. Still giving the error that "input empty"