# Can't get POST to work with Powershell and Bitbucket

Tags: powershell, curl, post, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to POST a file to the 'Downloads' section of a Bitbucket repository. I'm following [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/downloads#post) page from Bitbucket's documentation. I'm trying to do this by writing a Powershell script. I've managed to get the GET method to work with:

```
#Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -Uri https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myBitbucketUsername/myBitbucketRepoName/downloads?access_token=9EtOz9JDeWGwxTLKx3ya2oPE8g652GoLN0cMmtD0Ncvkf2OXoio0bcXwSigNE9AXTT2aj6qmbS5XHae7rIc%3D"&"scopes=pipeline%3Avariable+webhook+snippet%3Awrite+wiki+issue%3Awrite+pullrequest%3Awrite+repository%3Adelete+repository%3Aadmin+project%3Awrite+team%3Awrite+account%3Awrite"&"expires_in=3600 -OutFile .\file.txt
```

In order to get that GET to work I had to add the access token which I made through Bitbucket (hence all the text for the access token portion of the Uri).

I'm not sure how to perform the POST. I've tried several things including something similar to the documentation:

```
curl -s -u myBitbucketUsername -X POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myBitbucketUsername/myBitbucketRepoName/downloads -F files=@Hello.txt
```

The error I get inside Powershell when running this command is:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'u' is ambiguous. Possible matches include:
-UseBasicParsing -Uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UserAgent.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\ScriptTest.ps1:21 char:9
+ curl -s -u myBitbucketUsername-X POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/reposit ...
+         ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I've also tried with the access token added to the URL (similar to how I did the GET).

The file I am trying to POST is 'Hello.txt' which is on my Desktop - the same location as my Powershell script.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I've followed briantist's advice and switched to using credentials instead. Now, I get a '`Bad Request (400)`' error. Here is my code:

```
$postParams = @{files='.\Hello.txt'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myBitbucketUsername/myRepoName/downloads -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

Comment: `curl -s -u myBitbucketUsername-X POST ` Are you aware there should be a space between `myBitbucketUsername` and `-X`?

Comment: @Milk oops - that's a typo from copying into the post. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

`curl` in PowerShell is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` (and so is `wget`). This was a mistake; they should not have done this, because the parameters are not the same and `Invoke-WebRequest`, while doing something similar, is not a drop-in replacement.

The error is telling you what the problem is: `-u` is ambiguous for `Invoke-WebRequest`. It has 3 parameters that could possibly be, and it's telling you what they are.

But critically, you're trying to use it as a user name, which `Invoke-WebRequest` doesn't accept at all (it takes a `[PSCredential]` object, not a separate plaintext user name and password).

So, you should [look at how to use credentials with `Invoke-WebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951845/3905079), or use `curl` directly, if you have it and want to use it.

One way to get around the alias is to call it with extension: `curl.exe`

Another way is to remove the alias: `Remove-Alias -Name curl`

Comment: I've switched to using credentials, but now I'm getting a Bad Request (400) error. I've added more info to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: @Roka545 you can't `POST` a file just by putting the file name in the body, [use the `-InFile` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563552/3905079).