# Powershell Invoke-Webrequest "No file part in file" CURL to Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert this working request done in Cygwin to Powershell:

Cygwin (Working):

```
curl -k -u curl:Password -X PUT -F "file=$($_)" https://$($appliance)/wse/customblockpage/file/en
```

Powershell (not working):

```
Invoke-Webrequest -Uri "https://$($appliance)/wse/customblockpage/file/en" -Method Put -Infile "$homePath\$($_)" -Credential $cred
```

Here is the error I get:

> Invoke-Webrequest : { "Error": "No file part in file", "Result": "Failure" }
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-Webrequest https://{IP Address Masked}/wse/customblockpage/file/en  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Answer (score 0):

The `{ "Error": "No file part in file", "Result": "Failure" }` is actually the error response from the web server and not a specific PowerShell error message.

In your cURL invocation, you are specifying form data with the `-F` flag, yet you don't appear to be doing the same in PowerShell.

In PowerShell, you can specify form data using the `-Body` flag like this:

```
Invoke-Webrequest -Uri "https://example.com/" -Method Put -Body @{ "file" = "hello.txt" }
```

If you need to send the actual content of the file, then you can use this as your `-Body` argument:

```
-Body @{ "file" = (Get-Content hello.txt) }
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is a good starting point.  I went ahead and modified to:
    Invoke-Webrequest -Uri "https://$($appliance)/wse/customblockpage/file/en" -Method Put -Body @{ "file" = "@./$($_)" }  -Credential $cred -ContentType "multipart/form-data"

This is the new error: "Language": "en", "Message": "Failure", "Result": "Failure"

Any ideas?

I tried changing from Put to Post, but I get the same effect.

Comment: If it must be sent as `multipart/form-data` then that is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491129/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-powershell-invoke-restmethod

Comment: In my comment it is set as contentType "mulitpart/form-data"

Comment: "https://$($appliance)/wse/customblockpage/file/en" -Method Put -Body @{ "file" = "@./$($_)" } -Credential $cred -ContentType "multipart/form-data"

Comment: Just setting the content type isn't enough. Windows PowerShell doesn't support `multipart/form-data` yet and so you will need to use the link I posted if it turns out to be necessary.

Comment: Also, `"@./$($_)"` doesn't make sense in PowerShell. The `@` is curl syntax for importing the content from a file. I've edited my answer to show the PowerShell equivalent.